# Change Tableau data source from online to offline

Tags: tableau-api

The current Tableau file has an online data source (i.e. you need to connect to a server when you click on the "data source" button on the bottom left of the common Tableau Desktop interface).

What I would like to do is to disconnect the Tableau file from the online data source. Instead, all the data should be included in the Tableau file itself. The end result of this procedure should be that the data source can be edited without Internet access and without logging in to the server.

Which features of Tableau Desktop would I need to use?

Comment: An extract will make it offline but you can't edit the data inside a tde. Sounds like you just want to connect to a file based data source: txt, csv, Excel, JSON on your local machine.

Comment: Is there any way to disconnect the online data source, download the online data source, and reconnect to the offline data source without destroying the layout of the current file?

Comment: You could if you use a cloud storage solution like Dropbox or Google Drive or One Drive, syncing the file from the cloud to your local machine. Many cloud storage services will offer a sync mechanism for offline use. But you are still left with a file-based data source in that instance. Not sure if that's what you are after or not.

Comment: I would like to transition to a file based data source, correct. My question would be how to transition from an online data source to a file based data source without destroying the current Tableau dashboards, worksheets,  measures, dimensions, parameters, etc.

Comment: Easiest way is to create a new data source in Tableau that points to your new file and set it up to match your current dimensions and measures. Then right-click on the data source and choose the Replace Data Source option in the popup menu.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your data source from Tableau Desktop, and choose create local copy. Then save-as your workbook as a packaged workbook (i.e. a twbx file)

As Sam M mentioned, you may end up with a naked extract -- an extract that is no longer associated with the originally source file. If that's a problem, you can right click on your data source, and export to CSV, and then connect to that and replace data source.